# Can we update the Stack Overflow Help Center ourselves as a contributor?

Tags: support, help-center

Perhaps a GitHub repository that accepts pull requests? Or is raising a feature request on Meta Stack Overflow the only and right way to go?

To clarify, I am not asking for help updating any particular page via this question. I'm asking how to update a page in general. I have seen in several other companies that documentation is open source. Considering Stack Overflow is a website built on community collaboration, I thought a similar mechanism would be available on Stack Exchange

Comment: What is it about the Help Center that you want to update?

Comment: @F1Krazy This question was not about any specific help center post. I wanted to find out if there is (and if not, request for) a way to contribute to the help center directly in the form of perhaps pull requests. I do have a particular page that I want to update, but I do not intend to make this question specific to that

Comment: Mods can edit certain parts of it, if there's something that needs to be edited, make a meta post about it and if there's enough concensus mods can either make it happen or escalate to staff

Comment: It seems clear that you want to know *how this works*, so I retagged the question as [tag:support]. The required tags are not for saying what your question here is about; they're for saying what kind of tag it is. A [tag:feature-request] question sounds like you are proposing to change how the site works or what the processes are. @KevinB : retagged thus, your comment seems worth an answer to me. Unless there's a duplicate for this somewhere - which I'd think there *should* be by now, long ago; but I'm not aware of one.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I intentionally tagged it as a feature request, to ask for the feature to be added if it doesn't already exist

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I thought the same, but I couldn't find any duplicate when I tried to search

Comment: As much as I like this idea, I'm not really interested in yet another review queue that allowing general users to edit the help docs would require. I'm also only marginally interested in the flame wars that would break out, and me... I LOVE trolling, so that's saying something.

Comment: The documentation represents the (probably severely outdated) view of the company as to what is and is not allowed on the site - most notably what questions and answers are allowed in. We have no business rewriting any of that ourselves. Essentially the documentation tries to do too much at the same time IMO, as you are correct to identify that parts of it *could* be maintained in a wiki fashion. But that is why the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow) exists - to have documentation we can edit ourselves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Meta SO (here!) is the place to discuss changes to the SO Help Center. Once a proposed change has a consensus, one of several things can happen:

- A mod edits the page themselves. Note that only some pages (including parts of the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the top of the [index](https://stackoverflow.com/help)) currently are editable like this.
- A mod [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review)s the question and…

  - The page is edited by staff for the entire network
  - Staff allow SO moderators to edit that page on SO